# What language features are useful for fast-prototyping?

Tags: language-features, prototyping

What languages features are known for being useful for fast prototyping of projects before starting the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look into model-driven engineering. Several tools provide you with quick one-click prototyping out of high level (graphical) models.
For instance, [WebRatio](http://www.webratio.com) lets you design Business processes or User interface models and generates a running web application for you. It is based on BPMN and [WebML](http://www.webml.org) graphical notations.

[Disclaimer: I'm with Politecnico di Milano and WebRatio, and among the inventors of WebML]